# See clubbed categories in other in google pie chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

```
sliceVisibilityThreshold: .05
```

shows clubs all categories in pie chats below 5% under other. Is there a way to see the merged categories on hover over 'other'.

Comment: not possible using standard google visualization techniques -- for the _Other_ category, the chart does not display any tooltip, [custom](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content#customizing-html-content) or otherwise. it also does not fire `onmouseover` or `select` events. you would have to provide your own `mouseover` event, based on the coordinates of the _Other_ slice

Answer (score 0):

To display small values in use pie chart: `sliceVisibilityThreshold: 0` in the `options`.

```
var options = {
   title: 'My Daily Activities',
   fontSize: 11,
   backgroundColor: 'transparent',
   width: "100%",
   sliceVisibilityThreshold: 0,
   legend: { textStyle: { fontSize: 12 } },
   height: 400,
};
```

See in: https://jsfiddle.net/L03jf90s/2/